# How to return variable from this method?

Tags: objective-c, methods

I need to return the **longitude** and **latitude** from this method. This is from the `locationManager` code. When I log the lat, longt they give the correct values.

What I have been unable to do is to work out you to export/return the variables out of this method. How should I go about changing it?

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    double decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
    int minutes = decimal * 60;
    double seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    self.lat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@"Current Latitude : %@",self.lat);

    degrees = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    decimal = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude - degrees);
    minutes = decimal * 60;
    seconds = decimal * 3600 - minutes * 60;

    self.longt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.4f\"", degrees, minutes, seconds];
    NSLog(@"Current Longitude : %@",self.longt);
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I might be thinking about this too simply but you could create your own custom delegate or call your own method to handle the updates? What I mean by this is when didUpdateToLocation: is called you then in turn call your own method. Can you give an indication on where you want to return the values to?

Comment: you can save it in two double variable, that declare in .h file

Comment: You could return a CGSize using the width value to store lat and the height to store long.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to *return* the location from that method because you're not going to call that method yourself -- the Location Manager will call that method to give you an updated location. What you should do is to *store* the new location so that your code can use it later. Usually, that just means updating your instance variables, but you can do whatever you want with the location -- update you data model, write it out to a text file, etc. Storing it in ivars makes it easy to access the location whenever you need it in your code.

Comment: Many thanks - will try and implement this tomorrow and report back.

Comment: Have worked around this have got a mental black, can't just get it to work. If the method above generates the correct long/lat co-ordinates how do I export them from it, or make the calling procedure retrieve them. Being a void it expects to return zilch and been unable to modify it. Is there an example of what I am trying to achieve anywhere that OI can work off? Many thanks.

Comment: If the same object needs the location, it just uses `self.lat` and `self.longt` to get the latitude and longitude. Other objects that need the position would need a pointer to the object that has it. Usually, the location manager delegate will be some object that's accessible to the rest of the program -- part of the model, the root view controller, or maybe the app delegate. Your question isn't so much about location as about how one object can talk to another. Remember that for `a` to talk to `b`, `a` needs a reference to `b` so that it can say: `lat = b.lat` or `lat = [b lat];`